# How to track user bandwidth in an ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bandwidth

I'm looking for a way to detect bandwidth usage per-user on an ASP.NET MVC site.  We have a site where users can upload large assets and also download these assets frequently, and bandwidth is the most expensive thing for us, so we'd like to pass these costs on to our users.  When serving out these assets or when processing uploads, I could just keep a running total for the file sizes to the database indexed by the current user, but I'm wondering if there's a more generic way to do this?  Ideally I could track the bandwidth for every request and index it by the current user (that is, the value of HttpContext.User.Identity.Name) but I'm not sure how possible that is.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no attribute within the request object which can be used to determine the user's network band width.

Comment: Maybe this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338831/log-the-bandwidth-usage-and-request-time-in-asp-net-4-0